# Pivot stream data in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am reading data from Kafka topic and I want to pivot the data,
I am using the below code in spark shell

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "*******:9092")  
  .option("subscribe", "PARAMTABLE")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .load()

val schema = new StructType().add("ENTITY_ID",StringType).add("PARAM_NAME”, StringType).add("VALUE”, StringType)
val df1 = data.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
val dataDF = df1.select(from_json(col("value"), schema).as("data").select("data.*")
def forEachFunc(dataDF, batch_id): DataFrame = {
    dataDF.groupBy(“ENTITY_ID").pivot(“PARAM_NAME").agg(first(“VALUE")) 
    .withColumn("ProcessedTime", current_timestamp()) 
    .write.format("memory").mode(“append").save(“pivotedDataFrame.parquet”)
  }

data.writeStream.foreachBatch(forEachFunc).format("console").option("truncate",false).outputMode("append").start().awaitTermination()
```

But I am getting error, Someone please suggest a correct way of achieving this

Sample of my Kafka topic message is below,

```
{"PARAM_INSTANCE_ID":128748494,"ENTITY_ID":107437678,"PARAM_NAME":"Survey Required","VALUE":"Unchecked"}
```

[spark-stream-error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRcuM.png)

Comment: Please also post the errors you’re getting.

Comment: Hi James, Previously I have directly used pivot in stream value.Then i got error like "Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writestream.start()" So I referred the below link - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6563/pivot-transformations-for-spark-streaming/   and added foreachfunc and writestream ,but I am getting syntax errors...I am not aware of how to implement the foreach function in my code

Comment: Hi Vishnupriya, would you mind editing your question and adding the errors?

Comment: James, attached the error screenshot to the question

Comment: I edited your syntax a little bit on the question. you might review and take a look.

Comment: @James I am again getting error for the edited code`<console>:11: error: ')' expected but 'def' found.
def forEachFunc(dataDF, batch_id): DataFrame = {`

Comment: You need to put a `)` somewhere in the line `val dataDF = df1.select(from_json(col("value"), schema).as("data").select("data.*")
`